# jQuery custom content scroller traversed path styling :)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mousewheel, custom-scrolling

I creating custom content slider with [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and I need style its dragger. For example, if I drag it halfway -  behind the red (any color) trail. Аnd vice versa. Thanks for any advice)

Example [image]

```
(function($){
        $(window).load(function(){

            $("#content-1").mCustomScrollbar({
                axis:"x",
                advanced:{
                    autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true
                }
            });

            var i=1,
                imgs=["http://placehold.it/500x300.jpg","http://placehold.it/500x300","http://placehold.it/500x300","http://placehold.it/500x300","http://placehold.it/500x300","http://placehold.it/500x300","http://placehold.it/500x300"];

            $("a[rel='add-content']").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var markup="<li id='img-"+i+"-container'><img src='"+imgs[i]+"' /></li>";
                $(".content .mCSB_container ul").append(markup);
                if(i<imgs.length-1){
                    i++
                }else{
                    i=0;
                }
            });

            $("a[rel='remove-content']").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if($(".content .mCSB_container ul li").length<4){return;}
                i--
                if(i<0){i=imgs.length-1;}
                $("#img-"+i+"-container").remove();
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Here is [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PY66D/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope its will be useful.

```
callbacks:{
                    whileScrolling: function(){
                        if(!$('.pathScrolled').length){$('.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail').prepend('<div class="pathScrolled">');                                                         }
$('.pathScrolled').css({width: this.mcs.draggerLeft});
                    }
                }
```

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PY66D/5/)